# reusing part of tensorflow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have some starting value `s_in` and I want to execute some operations on it several times:

```
import tensorflow as tf

s_in_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
s_current = s_in_pl
def foo(a):
    return tf.exp(s_in_pl)

step_count = 1000
for i in range(step_count):
    s_current = foo(s_current)

s_in = [1,2,3]
with tf.Session():
    print s_current.eval(feed_dict={s_in_pl: s_in})
```

so firstly I put data as a placeholder, then use defined ops as input again.

The question is: Can the graph for `foo` be created once and then somehow reused w/o evaluating values in between (I need to compute a gradient)? Creating such graph takes some time when `step_count` is big and `foo` is complicated and makes a mess in TensorBoard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to "reuse" the same graph in your computation is to put `foo()` in the body of a [`tf.while_loop()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop). For example, the following code is equivalent to your `for`-loop based code, and results in a much smaller graph that is still possible to differentiate:

```
import tensorflow as tf

s_in_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
def foo(a):
    return tf.exp(s_in_pl)

step_count = 1000

# Ignore the first return value (which will be the final value of the iteration
# counter, `i`).
_, s_final = tf.while_loop(lambda i, _: i < step_count,
                           lambda i, s_current: [i + 1, foo(s_current)],
                           [0, s_in_pl])

s_in = [1,2,3]
with tf.Session():
    print s_final.eval(feed_dict={s_in_pl: s_in})
```